# Using Javascript to redirect a page

Tags: javascript, redirect

I have this bit of code

```
<input type="image" src="/wp-content/themes/happy/images/add-to-cart.png" name="Buy" class="wpsc_buy_button" id="product_<?php echo wpsc_the_product_id(); ?>_submit_button" onclick="alert('Cart Updated');"/>
```

How do I get that code to redirect to "example.com" instead  of displaying the "alert thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input type="image" src="/wp-content/themes/happy/images/add-to-cart.png" name="Buy" class="wpsc_buy_button" id="product_<?php echo wpsc_the_product_id(); ?>_submit_button" onclick="window.location='http://example.com';"/>
```

Note the single quotes around the url.

Answer (score 1):

```
  window.location="http://www.example.com";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.location.href = 'http://www.example.com';
```