# PHP query output page

Tags: php, output

The action on form page **venue_events** calls **event_list** and gives me the query output requested. If you type the link to the **event_list** page, it will populate a new query with out values from the form. Is there a way I can prevent the user from doing this or can I redirect them back to the **venue_events** page if this has been done?

Comment: yes. what have you tried? (Complete questions get complete answers.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you right you should validate the values **before** querying your database. If there are no valid values you can initiate a redirect using [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7070699/using-javascript-to-redirect-a-page/7070718#7070718) or meta redirection in html or using:

```
header('Location: http://www.domain.com/site.php');
```

That is only working of there is no output before the `header()` command.
In addition you could also check if you got back some results from the database. If thats not the case you can also initiate a redirect.

My suggestion to your comment:

```
<?php
// Was a search term passed?
if (isset($_POST['search']) && !empty($_POST['search'])){
  $sql=" SELECT * FROM venue_event "; 
  $search_term = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['AAC']); 
  $sql .= "WHERE venue = '{$search_term}' "; 
  $sql .= "AND state = '{$search_term2}'"; // $search_term2 isn't defined in your code at all...
  $sql .= "ORDER BY startdate ASC";

  $result=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
}else{
  // Do redirection here
}
?>
```

Comment: by using the this php shown below allows the user to type in the page directly and queries the database. Can I add something here to redirct if values are blank?                                      <?php
 $sql=" SELECT * FROM venue_event ";
 
 if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
  $search_term = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['AAC']);
  $sql .= "WHERE venue = '{$search_term}' ";
  $sql .= "AND state = '{$search_term2}'";
  $sql .= "ORDER BY startdate ASC";
  }
$result=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
?>

Comment: @user2072272: I've edited my answer in regard to your comment. But I'm still not sure if I got you right.

Answer (score 1):

In your landing page you have to check if you have a correct query, or correct data to build up your query. If not, for example because the user typed in the url directly, you can redirect the user to the page you want (probably the form one) using, if you have echoed nothing before, `header('Location: http://www.mysite.com/my_form_page.php');`.